# Read Azure Audit Logs from Local File System

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have downloaded the Azure Audit Logs in my Local Drive.

I am trying to read them from my local machine.

I am using below query

```
select * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('C:\Ran\Audit\Chevron\2020-04-10\01_48_07_838_426.xel',DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```

Got below error
**An error occurred in reading from the audit file or file-pattern: 'C:\Ran\Audit\Chevron\2020-04-10\01_48_07_838_426.xel'. The SQL service account may not have Read permission on the files, or the pattern may be returning one or more corrupt files.**

I have given full rights to folder : Chevron[On where the Audit file are placed]

Comment: Hi Baxy, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: am having same issue.  i downloaded some .xel files from azure and using the fn to extract data but it errors with same msg. am logged in with sa login. below solution didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I download my Azure SQL database audit file from blob storage and copy it to the Local SQL Server Audit folder.

Then login my on-premise SQL Server with admin account "sa", run the query and evertthing works well.

For example:

Read the audit file `01_13_36_510_0.xel` in blog storage in Azure SQL database:
[image]

Then copy it to local SQL Server audit folder and run the query again:

[image]

If you want read the audit file, you must have the [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions):

- **SQL Server:** Requires the **CONTROL SERVER** permission.
- **Azure SQL DB**: Requires the **CONTROL DATABASE** permission.

  1. Server admins can access audit logs of all databases on the server.
  2. Non server admins can only access audit logs from the current
     database.
  3. Blobs that do not meet the above criteria will be skipped (a list of
     skipped blobs will be displayed in the query output message), and
     the function will return logs only from blobs for which access is
     allowed.

Hope this helps.